# Print environment variables in NASM

Tags: environment-variables, nasm

I am trying to figure out how to print environment variables in NASM.

We learned in class that the number of command line arguments is stored in the EAX register, and the address of the first argument is stored in the location which is in the EDX register. However, this doesn't work for me since there is nothing written in the EDX register.

I have seen some other ways to do this, where the ESP register was used in some way, but I didn't really find a complete explanation.

I'd be very grateful if someone had a nice and clear explanation of this - for me - confusing matter.

Comment: You should specify the OS you're using. On DOS there's a pointer in the PSP that points at the environment.

Comment: @Fifoernik Sorry, I forgot - I'm using Linux, Ubuntu to be more precise.

Comment: Take a peek at http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following related post: [Why does this NASM code print my environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337857/why-does-this-nasm-code-print-my-environment-variables).

You can also take a look at the [startup state of a Linux binary](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html).

In short, environment variables are listed after a `NULL` value which follows command line arguments.